# KieServer and wrong jodatime version

Tags: drools, jodatime, kie-workbench, kie-server, drools-kie-server

I'm having a problem running Kieserver(6.5.0.Final) on Weblogic (12.1.3.0.0).
The problem is related to joda time, it looks like it's getting lost with its versions.
My weblogic.xml contains the tag to specific to use jodatime version of kiserver:

```
<prefer-application-packages>
    <package-name>org.joda.*</package-name>
</prefer-application-packages>
```

It is ok, it really forces WebLogic to use kieserver joda version.

But my problem is different. I'm adding one artifact in WB (Artifact Repository) - for example XPTO.jar - which uses a different version of the version that kieserver uses of the jodatime. (kieserver uses 1.6.2 and XPTO uses 2.7). I add it to my WB's project as a dependency, it shows in WB that is using jodatime 2.7 (All package incluses), deploy my project with rules to kieserver containers. When i do "fireallrules", it shows the following error "NoSuchMethodError: org.joda.time.LocalDate.toDate()".

Then I decided to replace the jodatime jar(1.6.2) from kiesever to the jodatime version I'm using on my project (2.7) (replaced at kieserver/WEB-INF/lib), then i tested and it works!! Of course, it doesn't look right to replace it, but I think it's probably a real problem on kieserver + Weblogic.

**Questions:**

**1)** Is it possible to make kieserver use the right version of any jar that was set in WB, without changing the jar version in kieserver directory(kie/WEV-INF/lib)? (In my case it happens to jodatime, It probably will happen in other cases/jars)

**2)** Is it "ok" to replace any jar version in kiserver directory (kie/WEB-INF/lib)? - That was the solution I found, but I don't know if it is politically correct to do that.

Comment: And your question is ...?

Comment: @laune I edited and posted my questions!